# Handling interface fatal error

Tags: php, oop, interface, error-handling, fatal-error

How can I customize the error message when a class which implements an interface doesn't contain requested methods?

Actually I get:

```
Fatal error: Interface function X cannot contain body in Y on line Z
```

Comment: I studied this workaround:
`@include_once $class OR die(); //sorry for the dirty @  
if(error_get_last())  
  echo "<div class='error'><p>The module named $class_name is not correctly implemented.</p></div>";  
else { ... }`
since this block is inside a loop, it shows which classes have missing interface methods.
I know it's not perfect but it's the only solution I've found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't intercept the error before it happens and throw an exception or trigger a custom error your only chance is trying with [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) and try to catch the Fatal error and parse the string that comes [`error_get_last()['message']`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) if [`error_get_last()['type']`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) is a fatal error.

*Notice: that the registered callback passed as shutdown function is called also when the script ends successfully, therefore you have to check if `error_get_last` is not empty.*

---

Apparently [you cannot](http://viper-7.com/3HK5J2) even walk the register shutdown function path, therefore what you are asking is not possible in PHP.

Comment: You can't catch this error, it occurs at parse / compile time and not at run time. A shutdown function will not work as the script will never be executed.

Comment: @nickb all fatal errors [can be handled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php#85727). You just can't do anything about the fact that the script will be exited whatever you do inside the shutdown function.

Comment: No, not all fatal errors can be handled. If that were true, [this script would print `shutdown`](http://viper-7.com/3HK5J2), but it does not.

Comment: @nickb, apparently you are right, I've always thought you could.

Comment: You can for certain run time fatal exceptions. For instance, your [example works](http://viper-7.com/Km2br0), because it's generated at run time.

Comment: @nickb, right. Then I guess it's not possible in PHP. Edited.

Comment: @Jueecy, I tried to +1 but I need 15 rep :( however I want to thank you, since I didn't know what you have explained to me

Comment: @Cerbero, glad to hear. I'm pretty sure you can accept the answer though. The "V" sign should be right under the reputation points for this answer.